# How to use tensorflow to solve explicit equation

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision

I am using tensorflow to process images and semantically segment clouds and classify them. To compare my machine learning results, I want to compare them to some simple measures such as the ratio of red to blue in a given pixel. One heuristic says if this is above 0.7, the pixel is likely a cloud.

I'd like to optimize that single parameter using tensorflow so that the input is an RGB image, and the output is a 2d matrix of a binary truth map: cloud/no cloud for each image. Loss could then be IOU, MAE, or SSE for the classification.

How can I use tensorflow to optimize that single threshold parameter on the train data set and then view performance over the validation and test sets? It would be nice to have all compared models (ML and heuristics) done in the same way for runtime and loss comparison.

An example of an input image:
[image: Example Image]
And the resulting binary truth:
[image: Example Truth]

Comment: so you want a network to learn the (per-pixel) equation "red/blue > 0.7"? I think that won't require much network.

Comment: I'd like the network to learn the X in red/blue > X which will be about 0.7 but I want to tune it and compare computational cost so that the comparison with CNNs and U nets are as similar as possible

Comment: ok so that's a single weight you need it to optimize... sounds like you want a *fully* convolutional neural network with... 1x1 convolutions? I'm not sure a standard layer type is limited enough. the activation could be something like `(1)*red + (-X)*blue + 0 > 0` and that already has more parameters than you need (the 1 is a weight, the 0 a bias). not my area of expertise.